# Checkout git project where submodule commit version does not exist anymore

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I am trying to checkout a github project, let's call it A, which has several submodules. So I tried,

```
git clone A
cd A
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

However, one of the submodules, say B, is set to a commit that doesn't exist anymore, so when I try to update it, I get:

```
 Fetched in submodule path 'B', but it did not contain 3ffeb07de8634a3540d185cbd16f76ebee704f7d. Direct fetching of that commit failed.
```

I checked it on github and indeed that commit does not exist anymore, I get a 404.
How can I update B to a version that does exist, I guess HEAD is fine, and then check it out?